# Xamarin Forms Tab Bar Icon

Tags: xamarin.forms, icons, tabbar

I try to add my own icons in the tab bar, but the image it colored at black and white, there are one way to conserve the icon with the original colors?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TskPa.png)

This it the look, i think that look really bad:/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlmkp.png)

I take Duolingo tab bar like my reference, do it some thing like that is so hard?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiGhV.png)

Comment: I'd guess DuoLingo is using a custom tab bar, not the standard OS one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the the `custom shellrenderer` to make a custom Tab bar. You can refer to this [Xamarin.Forms Shell custom renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers).

Here is the `MyShellRenderer` code in android project file. This method uses the code `bottomView.ItemIconTintList = null;` which can set the BottomNavigation Icon tint to null.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(MyShellRenderer))]
namespace App30.Droid
{
    public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
        {
            return new CustomBottomNavAppearance();
        }
    }

    public class CustomBottomNavAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
        {

        }

        public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            // code here
            bottomView.ItemIconTintList = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TabBar can have a different foreground for selected/ unselected/ disabled states, you can find that in the [Apperance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-appearance)'s section of the TabBar documentation.

Unfortunately, if the desired visual is to have multiple colors in the icon in a state, Xamarin's TabBar out of the box will not be able to achieve this since by default it flattens and unifies the icon into one "layer". As stated in comments, to achieve this you will need your own custom tab bar

Comment: Well, that´s sound logic, but i will need to learn a lot if i want to do that, thank u!